# Backpack Laravel chart widget

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using a backpack widget to add charts to my admin panels in order to show a graphical representation of data. but I want my charts to be bigger size but I can't find a way..

Answer (score 1):

You can resize a Chart widget like any other Backpack widget, using [the optional `wrapper` attribute](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-widgets#optional-attributes-1):

```php
'wrapper' => [
    'class' => 'col-12', // customize the class on the parent element (wrapper)
    'style' => 'border-radius: 10px;',
]
```